# Leaflet: How to show all layers on a map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to create a button that when clicked will toggle on all the layers EXCEPT for some specific layers. I am unable to make this work.

**How would I show all the layers except for the overlays named 'stuff' and 'stuff2'?**

```js
var map = L.map("map");
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);

map.setView([48.85, 2.35], 11);

var airfields = L.marker([48.85, 2.35]).addTo(map);
var docks = L.marker([48.85, 2.33]).addTo(map);
var stuff = L.marker([48.83602344356167,2.3617172241210938]).addTo(map);
var stuff2 = L.marker([48.840542852103084,2.3246383666992183]).addTo(map);

$("#clearAll").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".check").each(function(i, el) {
   el.checked = false; // Set new status (unchecked) first.
    $(el).change(); // Trigger the event.
  })
});

$(".check").change(function() {
  var layerClicked = $(this).attr("id");
  switch (layerClicked) {
    case "airfields":
      toggleLayer(this.checked, airfields);
      break;
    case "docks":
      toggleLayer(this.checked, docks);
      break;
    case "stuff": toggleLayer(this.checked, stuff);
      break;
      case "stuff2": toggleLayer(this.checked, stuff2);
      break;
      // ...and so on...
  }
});

function toggleLayer(checked, layer) {
 if (checked) {
   map.addLayer(layer);
  } else {
   map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-rc.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-rc.1/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="airfields" class="check" checked>Airfields
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="docks" class="check" checked>Docks
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="stuff" class="check" checked>stuff
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="stuff2" class="check" checked>stuff2
<br />
<button id="clearAll">
  Clear All
</button>
<button id="showAll">
  Show All
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the same as in `"#clearAll"` but force some checkboxes on and others off (your `"stuff"` and `"stuff2"`)

```js
var map = L.map("map");
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);

map.setView([48.85, 2.35], 11);

var airfields = L.marker([48.85, 2.35]).addTo(map);
var docks = L.marker([48.85, 2.33]).addTo(map);
var stuff = L.marker([48.83602344356167,2.3617172241210938]).addTo(map);
var stuff2 = L.marker([48.840542852103084,2.3246383666992183]).addTo(map);

$("#showAll").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $("#airfields")[0].checked = true;
  $("#docks")[0].checked = true;
  $("#stuff")[0].checked = false;
  $("#stuff2")[0].checked = false;

  $(".check").each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).change(); // Trigger the event.
  })
});

$("#clearAll").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".check").each(function(i, el) {
    el.checked = false; // Set new status (unchecked) first.
    $(el).change(); // Trigger the event.
  })
});

$(".check").change(function() {
  var layerClicked = $(this).attr("id");
  switch (layerClicked) {
    case "airfields":
      toggleLayer(this.checked, airfields);
      break;
    case "docks":
      toggleLayer(this.checked, docks);
      break;
    case "stuff":
      toggleLayer(this.checked, stuff);
      break;
    case "stuff2":
      toggleLayer(this.checked, stuff2);
      break;
      // ...and so on...
  }
});

function toggleLayer(checked, layer) {
 if (checked) {
   map.addLayer(layer);
  } else {
   map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-rc.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-rc.1/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="airfields" class="check" checked>Airfields
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="docks" class="check" checked>Docks
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="stuff" class="check" checked>stuff
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="stuff2" class="check" checked>stuff2
<br />
<button id="clearAll">
  Clear All
</button>
<button id="showAll">
  Show All
</button>
```

Comment: This worked great, but I had to add el.checked = true; to the showAll code.